# How to set a spinner item equal to a value

Tags: java, android, loops

I'm trying to set a spinner item **Equal** to a **Specific Integer**. I'm using **onItemSelected** to try and accomplish this, but the problem is, I need the **integer** that is set for the **item selected** to be **multiplied** by another **EditText** in the same row with the **Integer**. To mix things up a bit, all of my **EditTexts** in the row that I am trying to **mulitply** by, is **referenced** to a list then **iterated** so that I can add them all up. How do I get each **EditText** in the same row as the **Selected Spinner Item**(which has an **Int Value**) to **multiply** by the **Selected Spinner Item**? Here's what I have so far.... **Sorry for the mess!**

```
    int count = 1;
double gradeValue;
List<EditText> allEd = new ArrayList<EditText>();
List<Spinner> allSp = new ArrayList<Spinner>();


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void onClick(View v) {
    TableLayout tableLayout1 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);

    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.button1:
        if(count != 16){
            count++;

            // Create the row only when the add button is clicked
            TableRow tempRow = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
            EditText tempText1 = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            EditText tempText2 = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            TextView tempTextView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            Spinner spinnerTemp = new Spinner(MainActivity.this);
            EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            tempTextView.setText(count + ".");

            tempRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tempText1.setLayoutParams(editText1.getLayoutParams());
            tempText2.setLayoutParams(editText2.getLayoutParams());
            tempTextView.setLayoutParams(textView3.getLayoutParams());
            tempText1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            tempText2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
            tempText2.setId(count);
            spinnerTemp.setLayoutParams(s.getLayoutParams());
            spinnerTemp.setId(count);
            String options[] = { "A+", "A", "A-", "B+", "B", "B-", "C+", "C", "C-", "D+", "D", "D-", "F" };

            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, options);
            spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
            spinnerTemp.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

            allEd.add(tempText2);
            allEd.add(editText2);
            allSp.add(spinnerTemp);

            tempRow.addView(tempTextView);
            tempRow.addView(tempText1);
            tempRow.addView(tempText2);
            tempRow.addView(spinnerTemp);
            tableLayout1.addView(tempRow);
        } 
        }
        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        if(count != 1){
            count--;
            tableLayout1.removeView(tableLayout1.getChildAt(count));
        }

        break;
    case R.id.button3:
        int calculation = 0;
        double spinnerChoice = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < allEd.size(); i++) {
            EditText totalUnits = allEd.get(i);
            try {
            int units = Integer.parseInt(totalUnits.getText().toString());

            calculation += units;
            }catch (Exception e) {
                //ignore
            }

        for(int j = 0; j < allSp.size(); j++) {
            Spinner gradeTotal = allSp.get(j);
            try {
            int grades = gradeTotal.getCount();

            }catch (Exception e) {
                //ignore
            }

        }
    }
    }

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    if (pos == 0){
        //A+
        gradeValue = 4.0;
    } else if (pos == 1){
        //A
        gradeValue = 4.0;
    } else if (pos == 2){
        //A-
        gradeValue = 3.7;
    } else if (pos == 3){
        //B+
        gradeValue = 3.3;
    } else if (pos == 4){
        //B
        gradeValue = 3.0;
    } else if (pos == 5){
        //B-
        gradeValue = 2.7;
    } else if (pos == 6){
        //C+
        gradeValue = 2.3;
    } else if (pos == 7){
        //C
        gradeValue = 2.0;
    } else if (pos == 8){
        //C-
        gradeValue = 1.7;
    } else if (pos == 9){
        //D+
        gradeValue = 1.3;
    } else if (pos == 10){
        //D
        gradeValue = 1.0;
    } else if (pos == 11){
        //D-
        gradeValue = 0.7;
    } else if (pos == 12){
        //F
        gradeValue = 0.0;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You may want to try reducing your problem to the smallest amount of code possible before posting it. It's more likely to get a positive response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this looks harder than it should be cause you're using a table layout. If all your rows are similar and it isn't detrimental to your design, perhaps you might consider using a listview. then you could refer to things on the same row, simply by their position - conveniently supplied as a parameter.

But since you have it like this, you can get the index of the selected spinner item in it's position in the arraylist. which you can then refer to EditText arraylist. Off the top of my head, I'm thinking that you do a `setTag()` to your selected spinner items as a label. Then you loop through looking for the tag and doing something if it exists. Here is what i came up with. notice that i changed your onitemselected method to a method returning a double as i find that more useful for this kind of task:

```
    private double calcGradeValue (int pos) {
         if (pos == 0){
             //A+
             gradeValue = 4.0;
         } else if (pos == 1){
             //A
             gradeValue = 4.0;
         } else if (pos == 2){
             //A-
             gradeValue = 3.7;
         } else if (pos == 3){
             //B+
             gradeValue = 3.3;
         } else if (pos == 4){
             //B
             gradeValue = 3.0;
         } else if (pos == 5){
             //B-
             gradeValue = 2.7;
         } else if (pos == 6){
             //C+
             gradeValue = 2.3;
         } else if (pos == 7){
             //C
             gradeValue = 2.0;
         } else if (pos == 8){
             //C-
             gradeValue = 1.7;
         } else if (pos == 9){
             //D+
             gradeValue = 1.3;
         } else if (pos == 10){
             //D
             gradeValue = 1.0;
         } else if (pos == 11){
             //D-
             gradeValue = 0.7;
         } else if (pos == 12){
             //F
             gradeValue = 0.0;
         }
        return gradeValue;
    }

    public void spinnerLoop() {
        for(int i = 0; i < allSp.size(); i++) {
            if (allSp.get(i).getTag().toString() == "TAGGED!") {
                double gradeValue = calcGradeValue(allSp.get(i).getSelectedItemPosition()); 
                double calculation = (gradeValue) * (Integer.parseInt(allEd.get(i).getText().toString()));
//              do something with your calculation double
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Alot of if/else conditions. If you must use them, consider using switch statement.

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the adapter looking for the value that you want to match on.  Keep track of the loop's index. When you've found the match, set the spinner's selectedItem to that index.